# EqualTo() not working in Firebase DB call

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I run the following Firebase DB call, my result set is not filtered on 'Online', I just get everything returned:

```
var UsersRef = admin.database().ref(`Users/`);

UsersRef.orderByChild('OnlineStatus').equalTo('Online').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    ...
    });
```

var UsersRef = admin.database().ref(`Users/`);

[image: Firebase data image]

Comment: Can you post your data set on which query is being executed?

Comment: @Garry sorry for the delay. I've added the ref and an example of the data.